# Installing Kivy to an alternate location

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.5, site-packages

I have Python version 3.5 which is located here C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python35_64 If I install kivy and its components and add-ons with this command: python -m pip install kivy, then it does not install in the place that I need. I want to install kivy in this location C:\Program Files(x86)\ Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python35_64\Lib\site-packages, how can I do this?

I did not understand how to do this from the explanations on the official website.

Answer (score 1):

So it turned out that I again solved my problem myself, I have installed Python 3.5 and Python 3.6 on my PC, kiwy was installed in Python 3.6 by default, and my development environment was using Python 3.5, I replaced it with 3.6 and it all worked.